# How to dynamically adjust the left property of a Div

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, ajax

my title might not explicitly explain what i want to achieve, I have some div that are dynamically created, now i have an ajax request to delete any of the div a users wishes to delete, i want if ajax return success i will remove the div, i use .remove() method to remove the div and now my problem is after the image is been removed the space it contain is left empty so i need to adjust the left of all the immediate sibling to fill up the empty space.

```
  <div class="carousel-inner">
      <div class="mycrousel" id="photo1" style="left:10"></div>
      <div class="mycrousel" id="photo2" style="left:120"></div>
      <div class="mycrousel" id="photo3" style="left:230"></div>
      <div class="mycrousel" id="photo4" style="left:340"></div>
      <div class="mycrousel" id="photo5" style="left:450"></div>
      <div class="mycrousel" id="photo6" style="left:560"></div>
      <div class="mycrousel" id="photo7" style="left:670"></div>
      <div class="mycrousel" id="photo8" style="left:780"></div>
      <div class="mycrousel" id="photo9" style="left:890"></div>
      <div class="mycrousel" id="photo10" style="left:1000"></div>
  </div>
```

All this are on the same line from left to right, now suppose user delete div with id=photo5, i want to reduce the left of the div with id photo6-photo10 each by 110 to take up the space left by the deleted div

```
function scrollThumb() {
            var $scrollWidth = 110;
            var $photoId = 'photo5' //id of the photo that was deleted
            var $totalPhoto = $('.carousel-inner > div').length;//get the total number of div left;


            $('#photo6').animate({
                    left: "-=" + $scrollWidth + "px"
                }
             $('#photo7').animate({
                    left: "-=" + $scrollWidth + "px"
                }
              $('#photo8').animate({
                    left: "-=" + $scrollWidth + "px"
                }
              $('#photo9').animate({
                    left: "-=" + $scrollWidth + "px"
                }
                $('#photo10').animate({
                    left: "-=" + $scrollWidth + "px"
                },

           }
```

I know the above code is wrong but it's just an overview of what i'm trying to achieve, i don't want and cannot hardcode it i want it dynamically, and also i think of using a counter in the function but it won't work as the id's are not serial..
 Any help of one to make this work or even a better idea, thanks in advance.

**EDIT:**
[image]

I updated my question added am img, in the img below we can see i have 4 images now i deleted one and the space it occupy is empty, i need to dynamically change the property left of the other 2 images on the right side of the deleted image and reduce there left by 110px each this will make them fill up the space left by the deleted image, CSSwill do this for me if i use float:left and not absolute position, but i need to use absolute positioning to achieve my goal, any help thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I made a small jsfiddle, hope it's what you want:
https://jsfiddle.net/j45x4qjx/

Here is the function :

```
function deleteDiv(selector) {

  var mycrousel = $('.mycrousel');
  var div = $(selector);
  var divIndex = mycrousel.index(div);
  var otherElem;

  if (divIndex === 0) {
    otherElem = $(mycrousel.get(divIndex + 1));
  } else {
    otherElem = $(mycrousel.get(divIndex - 1));
  }

  // get left value between two member
  var leftElem = parseInt(div.css('left'));
  var leftOtherElem = parseInt(otherElem.css('left'));
  var leftPx = Math.abs(leftElem - leftOtherElem);

  // remove div
  div.remove();

  $('.mycrousel').each( function( index, element ) {
    if (index > divIndex - 1) {
     var $element = $(this);
     var left = parseInt($element.css('left'));
     // get new value of left or 0 if negative value
     var newLeft = Math.max(0, left - leftPx); 

     $element.animate({
         left: newLeft + "px"
     });
    } 
  });

 }
```

You just have to pass the selector of the div you want to remove, then it calculate how many pixel there is between this div and the closer one and remove that number to all other div.

Comment: so great of you, you've just made my day, the code work exactly as expected, that is what i was trying to achieve a big thanks,

Answer (score 0):

Why do you need to know which image is deleted? After all what you want is a neatly arranged list of images. I think this would suffice:

```js
function scrollThumb() {
  var $scrollWidth = 110;
  var $startingPosition = 10;
  var index = 0;
  
  $('.carousel-inner > div').children().each(function(){
    $(this).animate({
      left: ($startingPosition + $scrollWidth*index)+"px"
    }, 300);

    index++;
  });                                       
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your replay, i just edited my question and added image to help explain what i want , if u see this image u will see what i need to do is to reduce the left of only div that are immediate sibling of the deleted div, thanks

Comment: Hey you're welcome. I think I got the problem right the first time though. For images that's placed *before* the blank space, the animate function will simply animate them in place, which mean they don't change position at all. Have you tried out the snippet in your code?

Comment: yes i tried not working because it will also affect the first image and change the left too, since the second image is deleted only the third and fourth image need to change there left, and this is where i have big problem

Comment: Probably because your first element's original `left` is not `10px` as I deduced from your question's snippet? My answer is based on the assumption that the list of images start at `left: 10px` and increase by 110px for each image.

Answer (score 0):

You are doing this in a very inefficient way, opening this code on mobile makes it lag and jank.

simple put all the pictures in a parent element, and scroll that element. this way you avoid all the selectors and multiple animations on all the images.

If you deleted an image, css properties are enough to fill the gap of the removed image, + you can add cool animations with css for the transition!

Comment: thanks for your idea, but that is what i did exactly, all pictures in one parent element, now suppose the parent element has five images in it and all images are position absolute to the parent div, now if i delete one css will not adjust the left of the other for me because they are absolutely position and not float, how do i do this to make the child element sit close to other when one is deleted

Comment: do not make them absolutely positioned. why do you need to do that?